# AWS Lambda layer and local structure

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules, aws-lambda-layers

I'm facing a problem on how configuring my local environment to reproduce the behaviour of the prod env.

A simplified view of my prod env :

```
├── λf A
│   └── layer L
│
├── λf B
│   └── layer L
│
└── λf C
```

**A**,**B** & **C** are classic node.js lambda functions. **A** & **B** share some common dependencies (let's say `lodash.js`) that I want to group under a lambda layer : **L**.

For my dev env, I'm using Lerna (but that's not mandatory) to work as a mono repo with this structure :

```
.
├── packages
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── C
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── L
│       ├── node_modules
│       └── package.json
├── package.json
└── lerna.json
```

To ship **L**, all I have to do is installing it's dependencies and copying the content of *node_modules* folder into `nodejs/node_modules` path of my layer.

But what I'm currently unable to do it's making the module **A** & **B** to resolve their dependencies both in standard *node_modules* paths **and** the **L** *node_modules* folder.

---

Some solutions that are not acceptable :

- Duplicating the dependencies
- Adding the **L** dependencies globally in the lerna *package.json* (because in my real environment I have multiple layers)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, that would be the complex case when you are making environment based on Lambda.
It has separate running environment, so it is difficult to regard same as traditional environment.

But there is easier path that AWS provides.
How about creating your lambda function from Container Image?

Basically, Lambda Layer is "Hidden" file system layer in Lambda Virtual Machine. So it would work very similar to containerized layered package.

If you build your serverless function with container package, you can build your development environment same as production environment.

Reference :

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

You can follow this out of the box example to start :

- https://github.com/jinspark-lab/lambdakit